# jQuery add class if dropdown active, else remove class

Tags: jquery

I have a script that looks if the **unordered list** is visible, if it is, it will add a class. My problem is, it's not removing the class. Probably a noobie error, help appreciated though.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu0"><a href="/page/">IT Solutions</a>
    <!-- dropdown -->
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end dropdown -->
    </li>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu li').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {    
  var element = $(this).find('ul');

  if ((element).is(':visible')) {
    $(this).addClass('hilight');
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass('hilight');
  }
});
```

I am using `live` because i am having to work with an old version of jQuery.

Comment: Can we have html please?

Comment: try console.log((element).is(':visible')) before `if`. or x=(element).is(':visible') and print it in console

Comment: Don't forget to create these events inside $(document).ready(function() { });

Comment: Drop down? you mean unordered list right?

Comment: Sure let me upload HTMl

Comment: Can this not just be done with CSS :hover selector?

Comment: @Mat-visual Your mark-up is incorrect, you cannot have `ul` directly inside `ul`. Plus you are forgetting to shut your first `li`.

Comment: @Zenith Fixed html, was a mistake not closing li when i adapted it for here. I thought this was valid use for ul's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I guess you have missed out the toggling of the child ul and it causes is:visible to be always true.

http://jsfiddle.net/LR7t9/

```
$('#menu > li').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {    
  var element = $(this).find('ul');
   element.toggle();
   $(this).toggleClass('hilight');
});
```

You can use Hover as a short hand to mouseenter mouseleave:-

http://jsfiddle.net/J8tkK/

```
$('#menu > li').live('hover', function(e) {    
  var element = $(this).find('ul');
   element.toggle();
   $(this).toggleClass('hilight');
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is what he's after, +1

Comment: Yeah seems like he was not toggling the child elements.

Comment: Genius, thank you so much, you were spot on. Can i ask a question to understand things.. So in much simpler terms all this does it create a sort of on/off effect where toggle basically means on hover, toggle to block, add this class, and on mouseleave, toggle again to display none and remove class

Comment: No problem, Glad i was of help...Yes toggle basically switches the current visibility of element to its opposite. It is a short hand for checking the visibility and add/remove class manually.

Comment: What is your jquery version?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to loop through them. Try this:

```
$('#menu li').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){

    var el = $(this).find('ul'),
        len = el.length;

    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        if( el.eq(i).is(':visible') ){
            $(this).addClass('hilight');
        }

        else{
            $(this).removeClass('hilight');
        }
    }
});
```

Also, your HTML is wrong. You're not closing the first `<ul>`

Comment: Testing this, the class is being added to the ul, instead of the parent li, and it's also not removing the class :(

Comment: I misread what you said originally, sorry. Try the edited function.